# Metabox/Custom fields are not saving input data

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I think I was doing everything right but my data doesn't save. What is wrong with this code?

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'niloyrudra_add_meta_boxes' );
add_action( 'save_post' 'save', 10, 2 );

function niloyrudra_add_meta_boxes() {

    add_meta_box( 'niloy_meta_box', __( 'Additional Meta Boxes', 'impressive-child' ), 'niloyrudra_custom_field_callback', 'post', 'advanced', 'default' );

}

function niloyrudra_custom_field_callback( $post ) {

    wp_nonce_field( 'niloy_meta_box_id', 'niloy_meta_box_nonce' );
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_niloyrudra_custom_field_key', true );        

?>

    <label for="my_new_field">
        <?php _e( 'Description for this field', 'impressive-child' ); ?>
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="my_new_field" name="my_new_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>" size="25" />

<?php

}

function save( $post_id, $post ) {

    /*
     * We need to verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because save_post can be triggered at other times.
     */

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['niloy_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    $nonce = $_POST['niloy_meta_box_nonce'];

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'niloy_meta_box_id' ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    /*
     * If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted,
     * so we don't want to do anything.
     */
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.        
     if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Sanitize the user input.
    $data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_new_field'] );

    // Update the meta field.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_niloyrudra_custom_field_key', $data );
}
```

Comment: I tried the code as it is and seems it works correctly. Ensure you have the `comma` parameter separator for `add_action( 'save_post' 'save', 10, 2 );` because you are missing it and you should receive a Parse Error.

Comment: Somehow that comma was missing there while I was putting those codes but they were ok in my place. Probably my database is creating some issues.

Comment: But thank you so much... :)

Comment: Comma missing after ‘save_post’ in the add action?